# Drone Simulation using GMapping and Realsense R200

Tags: ros, drone, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'd like to simulate the *RTF* Drone from Intel which has the *R200* Camera as the main sensor. I'd like to use it for mapping simulations with *GMapping*. I want to build a launch file to load world, quadrotor_model, r200 camera and Gmapping in Gazebo in order to do some simulations. How can I create this costomized launch file?

I can't find a tutorial how to build customized launch files, so I'm trying some reverse engineering with the **hector_quadrotor** and **turtlebot_gazebo** packages. It's very confusing since I'm really new in ROS world.

Right now I have this:

```
<launch>

<!-- Start Gazebo with wg world running in (max) realtime -->

<include file="$(find hector_gazebo_worlds)/launch/willow_garage.launch"/>


<!-- Spawn simulated quadrotor uav -->

<include file="$(find hector_quadrotor_gazebo)/launch/spawn_quadrotor.launch" >
<arg name="model" value="$(find hector_quadrotor_description)/urdf/quadrotor_with_kinect.xacro"/> 
</include>


</launch>
```

I just found a drone model using kinect but would like to use the R200 camera.

**EDIT:**

I am trying to add the R200 camera model to quadrotor base. My `quadrotor_with_r200.urdf.xacro` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="quadrotor" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

<xacro:property name="M_PI" value="3.1415926535897931" />

<!-- Included URDF Files -->
<xacro:include filename="$(find hector_quadrotor_description)/urdf/quadrotor_base.urdf.xacro" />

<!-- Instantiate quadrotor_base_macro once (has no parameters atm) -->
<xacro:quadrotor_base_macro />

<!-- Intel R200 -->
<xacro:include filename="$(find drone_application)/urdf/r200_camera.urdf.xacro" />
<xacro:r200_camera name="camera" parent="base_link">
<origin xyz="0.05 0.0 -0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</xacro:r200_camera>

</robot>
```

Very similar to  [Hector quadrotor_with_kinect](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/blob/1b268f591a568ac6a5fdf1be06068d7879824a0c/hector_quadrotor_description/urdf/quadrotor_with_kinect.urdf.xacro), but I get this erros when I try to run the launchfile:

```
xacro.XacroException: Invalid parameter "name" while expanding macro "xacro:r200_camera"
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command 
[/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py 
/home/andre/catkin_ws/src/drone_application/urdf/quadrotor_with_r200.urdf.xacro myvar:=true] returned with 
code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(arg model) myvar:=true" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278437/drone-simulation-using-gmapping-and-realsense-r200/) by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-12-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-30**:
What's your question?

**Comment by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on 2017-12-30**:
How can I create a launch file to load in gazeebo a drone model, r200 camera and gmapping?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-31**:
This update should probably be a new question but checkout the solution to #q127541

**Comment by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on 2018-01-02**:
I could solve the problem, thanks a lot! Just removed the `name="camera"` in the `quadrotor_with_r200.urdf.xacro`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the [`urdf` tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials) and learn how `urdf` and `xacro` files work. Then, you can use this [R200 `xacro` file](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense_samples_ros/blob/kinetic-devel/realsense_ros_camera/urdf/_r200.urdf.xacro) to replace the kinect in the drone you found.

You can probably do this by using the [quadrotor base `xacro` file](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/blob/HEAD/hector_quadrotor_description/urdf/quadrotor_base.urdf.xacro) in the [`hector_quadrotor_description` package](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor_description) and adding that R200 `xacro` file that I linked to.

If you call this new file `quadrotor_r200.xacro` then you can load this into Gazebo by using a launch file (let's call it `spawn_quadrotor.launch`) similar to

```
<launch>
  <!-- load model -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(arg model) myvar:=true"/>
  <!-- Spawn a robot into Gazebo -->
  <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model quadrotor"/>
</launch>
```

The run this launch file as

```
roslaunch my_package spawn_quadrotor.launch model:=/path/to/quadrotor_r200.xacro
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andreluizfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/32882/andreluizfc/) on 2017-12-30**:
Thanks a lot! I was trying to figure out those `urdf` and `xacro` files. Thanks for the **R200** camera model. I'll definitely study them. Cheers!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-30**:
No problem. If this solved your problem, please click the checkmark to mark the answer as correct.